# Reflection GetValue null property

Tags: c#, .net, null, system.reflection

This method compares two objects of the same class:

```
foreach (var field in fields.Where(field => !objTarget
        .GetType().GetProperty(field).GetValue(objTarget, null)
        .Equals(obj.GetType().GetProperty(field).GetValue(obj, null))))
```

If the both property have values it works normaly, but sometimes i have a null property in one of these 2 objects, how can i deal with it?

EDIT:
If im comparing two objects, i.e:

```
var a = new Test();
var b = new Test();
a.Property1 = "1";
b.Property1 = null;
```

im getting the null reference exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ConsoleApplication1.exe

Comment: What isn't "working normally"? Is it throwing an exception?  If so, what is it?

Comment: That's not a method.  It's just part of a loop.  Perhaps you should show us some coherent code, like the whole method and how it's being called.  We can make some assumptions but those that appear obvious to me wouldn't lead to a NullReferenceException in the code that we've been shown.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - If property of first one is `null` - `null.Equals ....` would clearly cause the exception, also indeed there are plenty of other places where it could happen in that code (less interesting since OP said it works most of the time).

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov, ah yes, I missed that because of the line break at that point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using LINQ and `Where` method get the values to variables and put your condition inside loop:

```
foreach (var field in fields)
{
    var val1 = objTarget.GetType().GetProperty(field).GetValue(objTarget, null);
    var val2 = obj.GetType().GetProperty(field).GetValue(obj, null));

    if(val1 == null and val2 != null || val1 != null && !val1.Equals(val2))
    {
        // your code
    }
}
```